# What should I change to make this work

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] a) {
  if (a == null || a.length < 2)
    return;
  int j;
  for (int i = 1, temp = a[i]; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp < a[j]; a[j + 1] = a[j], j--);
    a[j + 1] = temp;
  }
}
```

It is expected to sort an array of int in ascending order. But for the input array `{ 1, 2 ,3 , 7 , 8 , 6 , 100 , 99 , 98}` , it gives output `[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`.

Why does this insertion sort code not work as expected?

Comment: What does it do, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: It is expected to sort an array of int in ascending order. For the input array { 1, 2 ,3 , 7 , 8 , 6 , 100 , 99 , 98} , it gives output [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code step by step and/or print the value of the various variables to better understand what is going on? In particular, this looks fishy: `for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp < a[j]; a[j + 1] = a[j], j--);`...

Comment: Even though I did not look at this code , it is uncannily similar to my code . http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/01wi/slides/Measurement/sld010.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By putting `temp = a[i]` in the initialisation clause of the outer loop, you make sure that it only runs once.  In the example you've given, `temp` will be assigned `2`, and you never change it to anything else.

Then in the rest of the loop, you end up assigning the value of `temp` to other entries in the array, whenever there's a larger entry.  So most of the array ends up being set to 2.

So `temp = a[i]` needs to be in the body of the outer loop, not in its initialisation clause.

Comment: I cannot believe i did that. Thanks though.